# Is the product of L2 norm and L-infinity norm convex?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an vector, and  $f(x) = ||x||_2 \cdot ||x||_\infty$, I was wondering if $f(x)$ is a convex function?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give some context? Why is this question interesting? Have you tried anything? Also it is not clear what $x$ is.

Comment: - No, it isn't.

Comment: @Michh $x$ is a vector, I have edited my question.

Comment: @A.Γ.thanks for the answer, but could you tell me why?

Comment: One can find a counterexample: $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n$ (with some large enough $n$) and $\lambda\in[0,1]$ such that $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)>\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$.